# Could mongoose models's save() miss some values?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I come here with the worst thing that could happens to a developer, i have detected a bug i am not able to reproduce.

I am working on a ranking game.
I have a `Tounament Model` that contains every players attending to the game.
Every 5 minutes i make a save of the Tournament's model.

```
TounamentModel: {
  Players: [ { _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, points: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 } } ]
}
```

Everything worked great, but after around 50 players, i started observing some updates which doesn't increase the amount of points of some players (everytime a game is over, i increase the players's points into the Tournament Model).

I first thought "maybe if a player increase his amount of points during the auto save, it doesn't work, maybe we have to wait untill the save's callback", but i wrote a short loop wich shows it's not true:

```
var User = new Docs['User']();
    for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        User.points += 10;
        if (i === 50)
            User.save();
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        User.save();
        console.log('Finally: '+User.points); // Prints 1000 as expected
    }, 10000);
```

So i am wondering, maybe if we have to many players into a single Model, maybe when calling `Tournament.save()` mongoose miss some updates into his Players Array.

What do you think ? Where would you look at ?
Everytime a game is over, i store the amount of points into other variables and it works everywhere except in this Model...
I even have an array which is a reproduction of the Tournament model that i use as a kind of cache system, and everything works great on it, so i am almost 100% sure this is related to mongoose/mongo.

Comment: you're doing a User.save() of absolute value - that's not an atomic update, so if two threads tried to do a save() on the same user wouldn't one of them overwrite another's save?  You should be using update with $inc operator, is my guess.  Actually, save would do the right thing if you did $inc() instead of just saving new number in points.

Comment: what version of mongoose are you using? looks like the behavior and operators around this were changed between 2 and 3.